# Plot least squares curve on Linear Log Plot

Tags: plotting, fitting

I have the following Data:

```
ExpDataCycles = {23, 69, 39, 25, 6, 43, 431, 328, 130, 614, 5941, 
   4506, 1876, 7898, 27015, 19154, 11586, 21470,
   130885, 431405, 84036, 1003250};
ExpDataMpa = {835.0265363, 823.4175447, 810.7696175, 799.6485919, 
   794.4425228, 793.0602069, 707.6873459,
   704.8236368, 693.9200675, 687.0103167, 609.8345095,
   602.6188024, 598.086902, 595.6103517, 591.5466695,
   584.7172701, 559.4813142, 556.6416481, 551.1841848,
   541.232457, 539.3158579, 385.3438704};
```

Which I plot using `ListLogLinearPlot`

```
ListLogLinearPlot[Transpose[{ExpDataCycles, ExpDataMpa}], 
 PlotRange -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {"Cycles [N]", "Stress Mpa"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "S-N Cyclic Loading Life at R = -1 "]
```

[image]

I'm trying to plot a best fit curve using least squares.

I plot using:

```
ExpDataCyclesMpa = Transpose[{ExpDataCycles, ExpDataMpa}];
LeastSqr = Fit[ExpDataCyclesMpa, {1, x, x^2}, x];
Show[ListLogLinearPlot[Transpose[{ExpDataCycles, ExpDataMpa}]], 
 Plot[LeastSqr, {x, 0, 1100000}]]
```

[image]

I understand the issue of the straight lines which i thick is because my x-axis is in Log form. How can I Plot a quadratic least squares fit between the LinearLog graph?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@rcollyer's answer is 100% correct, though it is telling that the `ListLogLinearPlot` of your data follows a polynomial shape. This tells me that your `y`-values follows a polynomial function with your `Log[x]` values. The plots seem to confirm this, as the curve fits your data much better:

```
Clear[ExpDataCyclesMpa, LeastSqr]
ExpDataCyclesMpa = Transpose[{ExpDataCycles, ExpDataMpa}];
LeastSqr = Fit[Transpose[{ExpDataCycles, ExpDataMpa}], {1, Log@x, (Log@x)^2}, x];
Show[ListLogLinearPlot[ExpDataCyclesMpa], LogLinearPlot[LeastSqr, {x, 1, 1100000}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: exactly what I need! Thanks guys!

Comment: Ok. So, I took the easy way out, +1. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `LogLinearPlot`, instead:

```
ExpDataCyclesMpa = Transpose[{ExpDataCycles, ExpDataMpa}];
LeastSqr = Fit[ExpDataCyclesMpa, {1, x, x^2}, x];
Show[ListLogLinearPlot[Transpose[{ExpDataCycles, ExpDataMpa}]], 
 LogLinearPlot[LeastSqr, {x, 1, 1100000}]]
```

[image]

Comment: @rcollyer.Thanks for the input but now I that I see the graph i might have formulated my question wrong. Basically I want a bestfit between the points.. Can you help on this?

Comment: @Nikolas perhaps my answer might help you on that.

Answer (score 1):

An Alternative:

```
a = Transpose[{ExpDataCycles, ExpDataMpa}];

b = Interpolation[a, InterpolationOrder -> 2];

c = LogLinearPlot[b[x], {x, 6., 10^6.}, GridLines -> Automatic];

d = ListLogLinearPlot[a, PlotStyle -> Red];

Show[c, d, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

Comment: Groovy! Thanks for the cool trick.

Comment: PS. Are you using MMA 9? I use MMA 10 an I could not get the minor grid lines to show up ([screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CGJoT.png)).

Comment: @Seismatic Yes it's MMA 9 (I don't have 10).